# Кодировка в базе и в richTextBox'e

Tags: c#, sql

Всем привет, скажите какую кодировку надо поставить в базу, чтобы вместо вопросиков, были русские буквы? Тип таблицы : TEXT

Вставляю данные из richTextBox1

Comment: я использую nvarchar и проблем с кирилицей не наблюдал или вы о чём-то другом?

Answer (score 1):

Нужен collation, содержащий кириллицу.

Если collation по умолчанию не кириллический, то можно задать его явно для символьных столбцов.